# Comparing two directories with subdirectories to find any changes?

Tags: python, compare, directory

For starters I've only been playing with python for about a 2 weeks now and im relatively new to its proccessess, I'm trying to create a script that compares two directories with subdirectories and prints out ANY changes. I've read articles on hear about using os.walk to walk the directories and I've managed to write the script that prints all the files in a directory and its subdirectories in a understandable manner. I've also read on here and learned how to compare two directories but it only compares 1 file deep.

```
import os
x = 'D:\\xfiles'
y = 'D:\\yfiles'
q= [ filename for filename in x if filename not in y ]
print q
```

Obviously that does not do what I want it to. This however is listing all files and all directories.

```
import os
x = 'D:\\xfiles'
x1 = os.walk(x)
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in x1:
     print ('Directory: %s' % dirName)
     for fname in fileList:
     print ('\%s' % fname)
```

How do I combine them and get it to work?

Comment: Perhaps [`diff -r`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) has what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Write a function to aggregate your listing.

```
import os

def listfiles(path):
    files = []
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(path):
        dir = dirName.replace(path, '')
        for fname in fileList:
            files.append(os.path.join(dir, fname))
    return files

x = listfiles('D:\\xfiles')
y = listfiles('D:\\yfiles')
```

You could use a list comprehension to extract the files that are not in both directories.

```
q = [filename for filename in x if filename not in y]
```

But using [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) is much more efficient and flexible.

```
files_only_in_x = set(x) - set(y) 
files_only_in_y = set(y) - set(x)
files_only_in_either = set(x) ^ set(y)
files_in_both = set(x) & set(y)
all_files = set(x) | set(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that best way to go will be external programs, as @Robᵩ suggests in the comment.

Using Python I would recommend doing following:

```
import os

def fileIsSame(right, left, path):
    return os.path.exists (os.path.join(left, path.replace(right, '')));

def compare(right, left):
    difference = list();
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(right):
        for name in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, name);
            # check if file is same
            if fileIsSame(right, left, path):
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                    # recursively check subdirs
                    difference.extend(compare(path, left));
            else:
                # count file as difference
                difference.append(path);

    return difference;
```

This approach lacks normal `fileIsSame` function that would make sure files are same by content or by date modified and be sure to handle paths correctly (as I'm not sure this variant will). This algorithm requres you to specify full paths.

Usage example:

```
print (compare(r'c:\test', r'd:\copy_of_test'));
```

If second folder is copy of first, all the differences in paths (different disk letter and foldername) is ignored. Output will be `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def ls(path):
    all = []
    walked = os.walk(path)
    for base, sub_f, files in walked:           
        for sub in sub_f:           
            entry = os.path.join(base,sub)
            entry = entry[len(path):].strip("\\")
            all.append(entry)

        for file in files:          
            entry = os.path.join(base,file)
            entry = entry[len(path):].strip("\\")
            all.append(entry)
    all.sort()
    return all

def folder_diff(folder1_path, folder2_path):
    folder1_list = ls(folder1_path);
    folder2_list = ls(folder2_path);
    diff = [item for item in folder1_list if item not in folder2_list]
    diff.extend([item for item in folder2_list if item not in folder1_list])
    return diff
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done a code that check two directory recursively, and if there is different, it would point out the line that different.

```
import os


FOLDER_A = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'folder_a')
FOLDER_B = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'folder_b')


def load_directory(directory):

    files = set()
    directories = set()
    
    for file_or_directory in os.listdir(directory):
        file_or_directory_path = f'{directory}/{file_or_directory}'

        if os.path.isfile(file_or_directory_path):
            files.add(file_or_directory)
        else:
            directories.add(file_or_directory)
    
    return files, directories



def compare_files(a, b):
    assert os.path.isfile(a)
    assert os.path.isfile(b)

    with open(a, 'r') as file:
        file_a = file.read()
    
    with open(b, 'r') as file:
        file_b = file.read()


    if file_a != file_b:
        file_a_lines = file_a.split('\n')
        file_b_lines = file_b.split('\n')

        if len(file_a_lines) != len(file_b_lines):
            print(f'Two file {a} and {b} have different length, of {len(file_a_lines)} and {len(file_b_lines)}')
            return False

        compare_lines = zip(file_a_lines, file_b_lines)

        index = 0
        for i in compare_lines:
            index += 1
            if i[0] != i[1]:
                print(f'Different found in file {a} and {b}, at line number {index}')
                return False
        
        print('Some thing wrong')
        return False


    return True


def compare_directories(a, b):

    assert not os.path.isfile(a)
    assert not os.path.isfile(b)
    
    a_files, a_directories = load_directory(a)
    b_files, b_directories = load_directory(b)

    if (a_files != b_files):
        print(f'Different Found In {a} and {b} directories files')
        print(f'A: {a_files}\nB: {b_files}')
        return False
    
    if (a_directories != b_directories):
        print(f'Different Found In {a} and {b} directories subdirectories')
        print(f'A: {a_directories}\nB: {b_directories}')
        return False
    
    for files in a_files:
        if not compare_files(f'{a}/{files}', f'{b}/{files}'):
            return False
    
    for directories in a_directories:
        if not compare_directories(f'{a}/{directories}', f'{b}/{directories}'):
            return False
    
    return True


def main():
    print(compare_directories(FOLDER_A, FOLDER_B))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```