# python detect new files without walk

Tags: python, os.walk

There are lots of questions about using python to determine whether files were modified within a directory (see [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041889/how-could-python-iterate-the-directoriy-and-detect-the-new-files)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251993/comparing-two-directories-with-subdirectories-to-find-any-changes)]). Invariably the answer to these questions involves walking through the directory (`os.walk`) to check things individually.

Is there any way to do this without a walk?

I have a large/deep directory structure and it is costly to check each subdirectory (and its subdirectories, recursively). I am wondering if this task can be accomplished only looking at a top level directory.

In this schema, the modification time of `dir` changes when `subdir` is created. But it does not change when `file` is created. The problem would be solved if modification times were affected by all child files and directories.

```
dir/
|--- subdir/
│   |------- file
```

A quick script to facilitate testing:

```
import os

os.system('rm -rf dir')

os.system('mkdir dir')
m1 = os.path.getmtime('dir')

os.system('mkdir dir/subdir')
m2 = os.path.getmtime('dir')

os.system('touch dir/subdir/file')
m3 = os.path.getmtime('dir')

print m1 == m2 # False
print m2 == m3 # True
```

Comment: Do you need to just determine that some file from the root directory was modified (true or false) output, or do you need to determine the file that was modified as well? Will files/directories ever be created or deleted, or just modified?

Comment: Thanks for asking! The most common scenario I am addressing requires only knowing if any file has been modified. Creations and deletions are more common than modifications.

Comment: Would directories ever be created and deleted or files only?

Comment: In my case both directories and files can be created at any time. So this is a general case where we want to know if _anything_ has been done within _any_ depth of subdirectory.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: Linux can be assumed, though an approach general to mac/windows is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only use Linux you can consider using something based on inotify, specifically [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial).

inotify is hooked into the operating system so as the os makes file changes it triggers notify events into your application. However, you may potentially find challenges if you need to use a platform other than Linux and may need to use a different library. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84351/how-does-inotify-work) is more information about how inotify works.

If you need something that will work on Mac OS, Linux, and Windows you can also consider [Watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/). This uses the platform specific file watching facility:

- Windows: FindFirstChangeNotification API
- Mac OS: FS Events
- Linux: inotify

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699293/how-to-monitor-a-complete-directory-tree-for-changes-in-linux) may be similar to your question as well.

Comment: Nice idea! AFAICT the approach here would be to create a daemon that walks (https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python2/pyinotify.py#L2119) and triggers a process on update. This is slightly better than the current state of affairs but does not solve the base problem (detection _without walking_).

Comment: Fundamentally there has to be at least 1 time to walk the full directory. This initial walk should set the initial modification watches in the directory. I wonder though if new file creations need to be detected by another full walk or they get triggered on inotify watches which don't require full directory traversal.

Comment: There is one way to test this by patching the os.path.walk function in pyinotify and seeing that when new files are created a full walk is not triggered.

Comment: Is this some basic CS principle that i do not know? If it is true that we need at least _one_ walk then the answer to my question is "you can't".

Comment: My mistake, I shouldn't have said this is a "Fundamental" principle. There could be some system implementation which makes it possible to not need an initial walk, but for a system like inotify which sets watch events on individual files and directories there needs to be an initial walk (since it needs to visit and set a watch at least once).